# How to Query Function Google Spreadsheet - Data filtering based on multiple criteria (multiple columns to check at once)

Tags: filtering, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that contains five (5) sheets, and we are starting to use them as a basic CRM to manage tasks, projects, deadlines and customers in a very basic fashion.
We assign tasks to each other in the first sheet "TaskRecords", and then we will populate the other sheets with the information there.
This the google spreadsheet (with mock data):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkB1z6YLt9N_dDU0VGgyZjN5cGt2UmtRb05FbWRRZ1E#gid=6

What I would like to achieve is to filter by means of a Query function or so, to use the spreadsheet as a database and filter the following: Taks by Team Member, by Customer, by Deadline, by Project, etc, and displaying the on other sheets.
I tried with Query formula: `=QUERY(TaksRecords!A2:I17; "select A, B, C, D, E, F, H, I where G="AL""; 1)`. Where I would like to filter everything that Team Member "AL" has been assigned to do, but I'm missing something.
I also tried to pull data out to other sheets using `Arrayformula`, but it only fetchs the cells I tell it to, and does no filtering based on multiple criteria at the same time.
Furthermore, there will be new rows of data added every day.

Maybe there is some script already written that solves this, I've been testing for several days with different options but couldn't get them to work.

Any hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of quotes. Try this, with single quotes around the name 'AL':

```
=QUERY(TaksRecords!A2:I17; "select A, B, C, D, E, F, H, I where G='AL'"; 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this query

```
=QUERY(JOURNAL!A1:E100, "select A, B, C, D, E where col1='Fruit' and Col2='Sweet'", 1)
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) There are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in this area, but I would use FILTER instead of QUERY. I use Query for a pre-defined formula to find certain records, and Filter to take a large quantity of records and narrow it down by certain defined criteria. Query is nice and clean, but it appears FILTER will suit your needs better.

Answer (score -1):

How about doing a query of two conditions like:

```
WHERE Col1='Fruit' AND Col2='Sweet'
```