# How to Query Function in Google Sheets (data filtering to pull data to other sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, filtering

I found this [How to Query Function Google Spreadsheet - Data filtering based on multiple criteria (multiple columns to check at once)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677202/how-to-query-function-google-spreadsheet-data-filtering-based-on-multiple-crit/18677979#18677979?newreg=de8700e52df4429c86681e3a675174c3) to be super helpful and thanks to @mogsdad for their reply. I'm hoping someone can help me with something very similar that I just cannot get to work. I've tried changing the query string in every way that I know how but cannot get it to pull data into the sheets properly.

When I have students fill in a form I want the data from their submissions to be pulled to other sheets based on their period. The sheet the data originates from is called "Responses" and there are 4 more sheets on which I hope the data will end up.

Link to document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ai9OxTXw1vPUdFFfMkJCM2REVU5xYzRxVFhHd2p1b0E&usp=sharing

I tried this query formula (and it sort of worked for 1st period but not for the other ones):

=QUERY(Responses!A2:I17; "select A, B, C, D, E, F where D='1st Period'"; 1)

Thank you in advance for helping a very stressed-out teacher!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting only the first 17 rows (`A2:I17`) as the range - which explains why only the '1st Period' works.

You should change the range to include all rows. Something like `A2:I` should work.

Comment: Thank you so very much! You have saved me so much time. Thank you a million more times!